# How is this generic function is used

Tags: c, linux, macros

I am going through code where some write has been made to some register. Now they made it as a generic function so that write to different register has to go through the same function:

```
   #define RGS(x) \
     static inline void write_##x(u8 val) \
     { \
     }

#define REGW(x) RGS(x)

write_wdc(val);
```

Now I want to know when the call to write_wdc is made, how it is replaced by these macros.

Comment: `##` is [Token-Pasting Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y.aspx)

Comment: yes ## I understood that part.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't show the macro actually being used, in order for the final line (the call) to work, there also has to be something like:

```
REGW(wdc)
```

somewhere in the code, to use the macro. The above will be replaced by the preprocessor with:

```
RGS(wdc)
```

Which in turn will be replaced with

```
static inline void write_wdc(u8 val) { }
```

I assume the body of the function is missing from your macro declaration too, I would expect something like `x = val;` in there to actually make the write happen.

This uses the `##` preprocessor operator to "glue" the words together.